# Scrapy crawlspider in python found an error "'str' object has no attribute 'iter'"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I get an error message that says:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'
2024-03-15 14:01:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

when I use this code:

```
class AuctionSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "auction"
    allowed_domains = ["auct.co.th"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.auct.co.th/products"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='p-2 card']/text()"), callback="parse_item", follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'auction_date': response.xpath("//b[@id ='product_auction_date']/text()").get(),
            'price_start': response.xpath("//b[@id ='product_price_start']/text()").get(),
            'order': response.xpath("//b[@id ='product_order']/b/text()").get(),
            'product_title': response.xpath("//div[@class ='col-md-12']/b/text()").get(),
            'product_regis_id': response.xpath("//div[@class ='col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12']/b/text()").get(),
            'total_drive': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_total_drive']/text()").get(),
            'product_gear': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_gear']/text()").get(),
            'product_color': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_color']/text()").get(),
            'cc': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_engin_cc']/text()").get(),
            'regis_year': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_regis_year']/text()").get(),
            'build_year': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_build_year']/text()").get(),
            'gas_type': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_gas_type']/text()").get(),
            'vin_no': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_body_number']/text()").get(),
            'engine_no': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_engin_number']/text()").get(),
            'endtax': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_endtax']/text()").get(),
            'stock': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_oderstock']/text()").get(),
            'price': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_price_other']/text()").get(),
            'gadget': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_gadget']/text()").get(),
            'remark': response.xpath("//b[@id='product_remark']/text()").get(),
        }
```

The error claims that "'str' object has no attribute 'iter'".

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please try to make a properly *minimal* [mre]. For example, if you only use one key-value pair in the dict that you `yield`, can you still reproduce the problem? if so, then there is no reason to show more than that in the example.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you specifically search for a string: (`/text()`)

```py
restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='p-2 card']/text()"
```

You need to replace it with the actual tag's xpath selector containing the link, something like:

```py
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='p-2 card']//a"), callback="parse_item", follow=True),)
```

I have no products for some reason, so the output I get is:

```py
{'auction_date': None, 'price_start': None, 'order': None, 'product_title': '-', 'product_regis_id': '-', 'total_drive': None, 'product_gear': None, 'product_color': None, 'cc': None, 'regis_year': None, 'build_year': None, 'gas_type': None, 'vin_no': None, 'engine_no': None, 'endtax': None, 'stock': None, 'price': None, 'gadget': None, 'remark': None}
```

Comment: After rerunning I got the same results with you, which I also found to be an error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "order": syntax error". I don't understand what it means. I went to look at the website and found that it looked like it was being updated. Could it have something to do with the error?

Comment: SQL error is not because of your code in this case. Yes, it can be due to devs updating their code.